# Pointer and Abstract class

Tags: c++, c, pointers, abstract-class

```
struct Abstract{
    virtual void methodA() = 0;
};

struct Test : public Abstract{
    virtual void methodA(){
        printf("Test message");
    }
};

class Foo{
    Abstract* abs; //I made it this way so that an instance of Foo 
                   //can easily switch between any class that implements 
                   //Abstract
public:
    virtual ~Foo(){
        delete abs; //free abs
    }

    void setAbs(Abstract* a){
        abs = a; //is there any other way to do this?
    }

    void changeAbs()//method to switch abs

    void show(){
        abs->methodA();
    }
};

int main(){
    Test *test = new Test();
//    Test test; //local instantiation will throw a segmentation fault
               //because abs is freed in the desctructor of Foo
    Foo foo;
    foo.setAbs(test);
    foo.show();

//    delete test; //using a pointer is fine unless freed
    return 0;
}
```

My concerns are:

1. If I **dont** free abs in the destructor and the user forgets to free his object that implements Abstract or if the user do it this way `setAbs(new Test())` , there will be a leak.
2. If I free abs in the destructor it will throw a segmentation fault if the user instantiate *Test* locally or he uses a pointer and deletes it eventually himself.
3. `Abstract abs` is also not allowed because it's an abstract class

I want to change setAbs() to something like this:

```
void setAbs(Abstract* a){
    abs = new Abstract(*a); //but copying like a normal class doesn't work on abstract classes
}
```

My question is, is there any other way to implement setAbs() so that it will make a copy of the argument passed?

If there's no other way, I'll just let freeing be the job of the user.

Comment: Uh, `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Note that `Abstract` does not have a virtual destructor, so `delete abs` produces undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying problem here is that you are not making it clear who owns this memory.

If your class owns it then it is safe to deallocate in your destructor.  Well, not the way you have it written, but in theory.  Read up on [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

If your class does *not* own the pointer then, well, don't deallocate it.  It's not yours to deallocate, so use it and do no more.

The safe way to handle memory is by implicitly enforcing a contract as to who is responsible for what.  If the user goes ahead and `delete`s your pointer, well, tell them to stop; it's not their business.  You could do the same using a `std::unique_ptr` pointer and the `get()` function.  The class won't stop you, how could it?  It doesn't care if you shoot off your own foot. RTFM.

Speaking of `std::unique_ptr`... why aren't you using it (or `std::shared_ptr` if appropriate)?  This is a solved problem, no need to come up with your own solution here.